# OpenCL creating wrong colours

Tags: image, opencl, gpgpu

I'm having an issue with an OpenCL image filter I've been trying to get working.
I've written many of these before (Sobel Edge Detection, Auto Segmentation, and such), so I *thought* I knew how to do this, but the following code is giving me some really weird output:

```
//NoRedPixels.cl

__kernel void NoRedPixels(
    __read_only image2d_t srcImg,
    __write_only image2d_t dstImg, 
    sampler_t sampler,
    int width, int height,
    int threshold,
    int colour,
    int fill)
{
    int2 imageCoordinate = (int2)(get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1));

    if (imageCoordinate.x < width && imageCoordinate.y < height)
    {

        float4 pixel = read_imagef(srcImg, sampler, imageCoordinate);
        float4 blue = (float4)(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f);

        if (1.0f - pixel.x <= 0.1f)
            write_imagef(dstImg, imageCoordinate, blue);
        else
            write_imagef(dstImg, imageCoordinate, pixel);
    }
}
```

So for testing, all I want to do is replace red pixels with blue ones, but this code will replace all matching pixels with WHITE ones.
As far as I know, my formatting for blue is proper RGBA formatting for creating pure blue (I've done this before without issue).

I'm using PyOpenCL as my framework, and I've made sure to set the image channel order for both the source and destination images as RGBA. In addition, I've also made sure to convert the source image to RGBA format (using Python Imaging Library) if it was not already in that format before running the kernel on it.

I've gone back and looked at other kernels I've written, and the formatting is identical. What am I missing here that would cause it to write white pixels out instead of blue ones?

Comment: If you simply read a pixel, decompose it into its components, reconstruct it as a float4, then write it, does the image remain unchanged? What about if you use (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) or (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) as the replacement pixel? Do those behave as expected?

Comment: I played around with all of the values of the blue float4 to no effect. For whatever reason, it's not applying the colour that float4 should represent to the destination image.

I've tried using an int4 with write_imagei instead of float4 and write_imagef and it had no effect, either.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't answer the first part of your question. I did try manually assigning each value to a different float4 (like item.x = 255, item.y = 0, etc...) with no luck.

Comment: Very odd. My only guess would be that the image format isn't what you'd expect, since `pixel` seems to work fine as a write value, but `blue` doesn't. The only thing I can think of is try to manipulate `pixel` to try to discover its format (e.g., by setting all but one field to 0, etc.)

Comment: It's even more strange. I tried manually setting the values of pixel, and it has no effect, except when I attempt to set (what should be) the transparency. Any attempt to modify pixel.w gives me a generic "clBuildProgram failed: invalid value" error. Again, I typically use RGBA format for my programs, so I know pix.w is where I should be able to modify transparency. How could a float4 not have a w dimension to modify?

Comment: So after more experimentation and hair-pulling, I've come to realize that I can change the green and blue channels with some success, but I have no control over the red channel's value (pix.x doesn't seem to "take" any changes). The alpha channel still throws compile-time errors when I attempt to modify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I think I've figured it out. For some reason, OpenCL's not so keen on letting you edit the channels the way I wanted to. I ended up solving it by simply adding or subtracting equivalent float4 vectors to obtain the resultant vector I wanted.

```
__kernel void NoRedPixels(__read_only image2d_t srcImg, __write_only image2d_t dstImg, 
sampler_t sampler, int width, int height, int threshold, int colour, int fill)
{
    int2 imageCoordinate = (int2) (get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1));
    if (imageCoordinate.x < width && imageCoordinate.y < height)
    {   
        float4 pix = read_imagef(srcImg, sampler, (int2)(imageCoordinate.x, imageCoordinate.y));

        //Full red channel, subtract this from original to remove red!
        float4 red = (float4)(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        float4 blue = (float4)(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    if (pix.x >= 0.9f && pix.y <= 0.1f && pix.z <= 0.1f) //If red, then replace with blue.
    {   
        const float4 outColor = pix - red + blue;
        write_imagef(dstImg, imageCoordinate, outColor);
    }
    else
        write_imagef(dstImg, imageCoordinate, pix);

    }
}
```

So in this case, by creating vectors to represent blue and red (without transparency) subtracting red, then adding blue, I obtain the resulting vector I wanted. Personally, I'm not sure why I have to do it this way, but I'm just glad I know what OpenCL expects me to do, now. Hopefully if someone else is having this problem, they'll find this here.